# How can I loop through docs to send a lot of mongojs data to a jade template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

So, I'm using mongojs. To get values into a rendered view, it was my understanding that one had to do something like this:

```
    app.get('/someurl', function(req, res) {
    db.mymongocollection.find(function(err, docs) {
    //console.log(docs[0].First);
    res.render('someview',{first: docs[0].First});
    });
    });
```

What if I wanted to move a ton of data to my view? Like the first names and last names for 20 people, but only if they play soccer? I understand that I can change the query parameters (to account for things such as only plating soccer), but **is there a way to loop through the docs index somehow?**
So I don't have to hardcode something like:

```
    res.render('someview',{first1:docs[0].Name, first2:docs[2].Name .....});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the array of documents to your template:

```
app.get('/someurl', function(req, res) {
  db.mymongocollection.find(function(err, docs) {
    res.render('someview', { docs : docs });
  });
});
```

And in your template, loop through it:

```
for doc in docs:
  h1 #{doc.First} #{doc.Last}
```